# Increase size of Amazon EBS volume: "Unknown label"

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I am trying to increase the volume of the root folder after running this command `growpart /dev/nvme0n1p1` 83

This is the error I receive

```
    WARN: unknown label 
failed [sfd_dump:1] sfdisk --unit=S --dump /dev/nvme0n1p1
sfdisk: /dev/nvme0n1p1: does not contain a recognized partition table
FAILED: failed to dump sfdisk info for /dev/nvme0n1p1
```

How can I get past this error?

Answer (score 5):

use the *resize2fs* command instead
eg:

```
$ sudo resize2fs /dev/nvme0n1p1
```

Answer (score 1):

**Verify the Device**: Double-check that `/dev/nvme0n1p1` is indeed the correct device and partition that you want to resize. You can use the lsblk or fdisk -l command to list the available devices and their partitions. Make sure you're targeting the right one.

**Check Partition Table**: If the device is supposed to have a partition table, ensure that it's not corrupted. You can use the gdisk or fdisk command to examine the partition table. For example:

```
sudo gdisk /dev/nvme0n1
```

If there's no partition table or it appears to be corrupted, you might need to recreate the partition table. However, be cautious as this can result in data loss if not done correctly.

**Create a Partition**: If the device doesn't have a partition or if you need to create a new one, you can use the fdisk or parted command to create a new partition. For example:

```
sudo fdisk /dev/nvme0n1
```

Follow the prompts to create a new partition and then try running the growpart command again.

**Check Filesystem**: If there's a valid partition table but you're still encountering issues, it's possible that the filesystem within the partition needs to be resized. After successfully resizing the partition using growpart, you might need to resize the filesystem to use the newly allocated space. The specific command depends on the filesystem type (e.g., ext4, xfs). For example:

For ext4:

```
sudo resize2fs /dev/nvme0n1p1
```

For xfs:

```
sudo xfs_growfs /mountpoint
```

Remember to replace /mountpoint with the actual mount point of the filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

For Nitro volumes, use:

```
$ sudo xfs_growfs -d /YOUR_EBS_MOUNT_POINT
```